# Compiling pcre 8.32 on AIX 6.1 64 bit

Tags: pcre, aix

I am trying to configure and make pcre using below command

```
./configure CC="gcc" CFLAGS="-maix64" CXX="gcc" CXXFLAGS="-maix64" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/ccs/bin -maix64" --disable-cpp --prefix=/usr/local/share/bld/pcre
```

configure works fine:
pcre-8.32 configuration summary:

```
Install prefix .................. : /usr/local/share/bld/pcre
C preprocessor .................. : gcc -maix64 -E
C compiler ...................... : gcc -maix64
C++ preprocessor ................ : gcc -maix64 -E
C++ compiler .................... : gcc -maix64
Linker .......................... : /usr/bin/ld
C preprocessor flags ............ :
C compiler flags ................ : -O2
C++ compiler flags .............. : -maix64
Linker flags .................... :
Extra libraries ................. :

Build 8 bit pcre library ........ : yes
Build 16 bit pcre library ....... : no
Build 32 bit pcre library ....... : no
Build C++ library ............... : no
Enable JIT compiling support .... : no
Enable UTF-8/16/32 support ...... : no
Unicode properties .............. : no
Newline char/sequence ........... : lf
\R matches only ANYCRLF ......... : no
EBCDIC coding ................... : no
EBCDIC code for NL .............. : n/a
Rebuild char tables ............. : no
Use stack recursion ............. : yes
POSIX mem threshold ............. : 10
Internal link size .............. : 2
Match limit ..................... : 10000000
Match limit recursion ........... : MATCH_LIMIT
Build shared libs ............... : yes
Build static libs ............... : no
Use JIT in pcregrep ............. : no
Buffer size for pcregrep ........ : 20480
Link pcregrep with libz ......... : no
Link pcregrep with libbz2 ....... : no
Link pcretest with libedit ...... : no
Link pcretest with libreadline .. : no
Valgrind support ................ : no
Code coverage ................... : no
```

While doing make I am getting follwing error:

```
bash-3.00# make
        rm -f pcre_chartables.c    
        ln -s ./pcre_chartables.c.dist pcre_chartables.c
     make  all-am
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_byte_order.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_compile.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_config.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_dfa_exec.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_exec.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_fullinfo.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_get.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_globals.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_jit_compile.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_maketables.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_newline.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_ord2utf8.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_refcount.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_string_utils.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_study.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_tables.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_ucd.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_valid_utf8.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_version.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_xclass.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_chartables.lo
  CCLD   libpcre.la

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_byte_order.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_compile.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_config.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_dfa_exec.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_exec.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_fullinfo.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_get.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_globals.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_jit_compile.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_maketables.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_newline.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_ord2utf8.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_refcount.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_string_utils.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_study.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_tables.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_ucd.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_valid_utf8.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_version.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_xclass.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

0654-210 .libs/libpcre_la-pcre_chartables.o is not valid in the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

ar: 0707-126 .libs/libpcre.so.1 is not valid with the current object file mode.

        Use the -X option to specify the desired object mode.

make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.

Stop.

make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 2
```

I have tried: using `OBJECT_MODE=64`, `q64` but in this case even configure fails.
Any suggestions are appriciated.

Answer (score 4):

Its resolved using follwing command:

```
./configure CC="gcc" CFLAGS="-maix64"  CXX="g++" CXXFLAGS="-maix64" NM="nm -X64" \
    AR="ar -X64" --disable-cpp --prefix=/usr/local/share/bld/pcre
```

Comment: Just an observation, but with Autotools you might be able to simplify to `CPPFLAGS=-maix64` because `CPPFLAGS` is used with both `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`.